# Implement js plugin for sublime text 2 using v8 plugin

Tags: javascript, plugins, sublimetext

I am trying to write plugins for sublime text 2 in javascript, using the v8 plugin. There is a demo javascript file called test.js, which seems to be a complete test plugin, but I can not figure out how to activate it.

Has anyone managed to write a plugin for sublime text 2 using javascript?

Is there another way to approach this? I mostly want to send text to javascript to be processed by my various libraries and then send text back.

---

EDIT:
I am using this project to get v8 working with sublime: https://github.com/akira-cn/sublime-v8

Answer (score 4):

You can try this plugin https://github.com/akira-cn/SublimeJS

Follow example:

```js
/** package.json **/

{
    "name": "JSDemo",
    "description": "demo plugin powered by SublimeJS",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "author": {
        "name": "akira-cn",
        "email": "akira.cn@gmail.com"
    },
    "main": "index.js",
    "licenses": [{
        "type": "The MIT License",
        "url": "http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php"
    }]
}
```

```js
/** index.js **/

defineCommand("Hello", require("hello.command"));
```

```js
/** hello.command.js **/

module.exports = function(view, edit) {
    view.insert(edit, 0, "HelloWorld");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with node.js. Simple python wrapper should do the trick.
An example of plugin build with node.js: [Sublime-HTMLPrettify](http://github.com/victorporof/Sublime-HTMLPrettify)

Comment: I am trying to do it with v8, via github project (see edit). Thanks anyway.